# how to retain text box selected values in php/html

Tags: html, forms

I have a form similar to below in .php. Whenever user selects in list box or type anything in the text box of my form, the moment they click on submit, it resets the selected value after loading and retrieving the data. I would like to retain the selected values at least until they navigate away from the page.

```
<form action = "samefile.php" method = "post">
Enter Start Date <input type = '"text" name = "startdate" >     </br>
Enter End Date <input type = "'text" name = "enddate" >     </br>
Enter Organisation Name <input type = 'text" name = "organisation" >     </br>
submit <input type = '"submit" value = "Fetch Data" >     </br>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe you should read something about form handling in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: To do this, you should learn Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo the post values:

```
 <input type="text" name="startdate" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['startdate']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['startdate']) : '' ?>" />
```

Please remember to use `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid code injection.

Comment: You really really want to use `htmlspecialchars($_POST['startdate'])`. Never forget to escape user input!

Comment: @sujanth..i just noticed..this code doesn't work for list box.. i used as below `<select name="listname" value = value="<?php echo isset($_POST['listname']) ? $_POST['listname'] : '' ?>"`

Comment: If you get 'value' from post.

you can store it in a cookie/session, of store it on the server.

use

`if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $_COOKIE['value'] = $_POST['value'];
}
$myArray = $_COOKIE['value'];`

same goes with session